# Deleting a Node in an AVL Tree

Tags: python, recursion, nodes, avl-tree

I am working on an AVL Tree right now and am just about done except for the deleting a node method. I am a bit stuck right now and need some help. The way I did it was to find the node to be deleted and call a balance on each of the nodes in the paths recursively, so that after the desired node is removed, a series of tree balances would do its work on the tree. Unfortunately, the balancing doesn't work as intended for some odd reason- I have printed things out to test what was going on and for some reason, if we had a tree like this for example:

```
    6
   / \
 3      18 
  \    /  \
   5  9    74
          /  \
         50   99
```

and say I wanted to delete the 9, so an imbalance would occur,
the balance would only balance the root node of 6, but not the node of 18...

```
def deleteNode(self, val, root, previous):

        if (val==root.value):

            if (root.right is None and root.left is None):
                if (previous is not None and (previous.value>root.value)):
                    previous.left=None
                else:
                    if (previous is not None and (previous.value<root.value)):
                        previous.right=None
                    else:
                        if (previous is None):
                            self.root=None
                return

            if (root.right is None and root.left is not None):

                if (previous is not None and (previous.value>root.value)):
                    previous.left=root.left
                else:
                    if (previous is not None and (previous.value<root.value)):
                        previous.right=root.left
                    else:
                        if (previous is None):
                            self.root=root.left
                return

            if (root.left is None and root.right is not None):

                if (previous is not None and (previous.value>root.value)):
                    previous.left=root.right
                else:
                    if (previous is not None and (previous.value<root.value)):
                        previous.right=root.right
                    else:
                        if (previous is None):
                            self.root=root.right
                return

            if (root.left is not None and root.right is not None):

                rval=self.maxValue(root.left).value
                self.deleteNode(self.maxValue(root.left).value , self.root, None)
                root.value=rval

                return






        else:
            if (root.value<val):
                self.deleteNode(val, root.right, root)


                if (root.right is not None):
                    print root.value,
                    print root.right.value
                    self.balance(root.right, root)
            else:
                if (root.value>val):
                    self.deleteNode(val, root.left, root)

                    if (root.left is not None):
                        print root.value,
                        print root.left.value

                        self.balance(root.left, root)
```

Solved- I just had an incorrect balance system.

Comment: I suspect the root cause (pardon the pun) of your problem is somewhere in your `balance` function, which you haven't shown us. Rather than showing us `deleteNode`, you may want to show us your `balance` function instead. (Put `deleteNode` in a gist or something so the question doesn't get overly long).

Comment: @Skorpius It would be helpful to future visitors if you could elaborate on your solution in an answer to this question.